# Proper unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm not quite sure if this question fits SO standards, but...

I'm experienced in using JUnit for testing of Java application together with mocking and so on... But there is one thing that I'm concerted about - **How to be sure that each class and each method is really tested?**

I found something that looks similar to what I want to achieve - [GrandTestAuto](http://grandtestauto.org/) (inspiration came from [testing tools page](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools)), can you recommend another (better) approach?

I have to test it (GTA) more, I'm interested in Spring, Mocking, Maven to work together, but I'm sceptical a little bit.

I'm using coverage reports also (JCoverage, JaCoCo), but this is not accurate, because when you test method `a()` that calls `b()` both are covered, but as a developer I want to write tests for `b()`.

edit:
I found [JUCA report](http://source.valtech.com/display/juca/JUCA+Maven+Plugin), I need to test this also.

edit2:
Ok, idea about `a()` calls `b()` has to be more.

See the ecample

```
void a() {
    b( "test" );
}

void b( String s ) {
    Assert.notNull( s );
    // ...
}
```

when `a()` is covered, b() is covered also, but the case that s is null is not and it often happens, because `b()` is not tested at all.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's too easy to game the coverage tools, so you need good developers to write good unit tests - trying to replace skill with tooling won't achieve the same thing

Comment: If method a() calls method b(), both *are* covered. I think what you're asking is, can you ensure that method b() is testing directly? @NickHolt is right, tools can't replace skill and experience

Comment: It's not an attempt to "replace skill with tool", but as I said, I have method `a()` and test for it. `a()` calls `b()` in release 1.0, but in release 1.1 `a()` calls also `c()` and I do not want to forget to write the test for `c()` also...

Answer (score 3):

I think that code coverage is a fairly good way of knowing what is completely untested, but it's not a lot more than that.

What I suggest is two things:

- Test Review - Same as code reviews, but for the code of the test. You wouldn't believe how effective that is
- Mutation Testing - Automatic tools that change the production code in runtime and check that the tests covering it are failing. I'm working with PIT (http://pitest.org/), and highly recommend it